# @JsonFormat on Optional property

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, option-type

I learned how to use Json and java.util.Optional together through this post:
https://medium.com/@harittweets/how-to-use-java-util-optional-and-json-together-12434f9d55b9#.r0kpo65f8

But I got another problem when the property of the class is in type Date and it must be formatted. So I use @JsonFormat:

```
public class UserBean extends BasicBean {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Optional<Date> dob;

    // getter and setter
}
```

I use Spring boot for My App, this is the configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.hag.prj")
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}


@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .modules(this.jdk8Module(), this.jsrModule(), this.parameterNamesModule()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Module jdk8Module() {
        final Jdk8Module jdk8Module = new Jdk8Module();
        jdk8Module.configureAbsentsAsNulls(true);
        return jdk8Module;
    }

    @Bean
    public Module jsrModule() {
        return new JavaTimeModule();
    }

    @Bean
    public Module parameterNamesModule() {
        return new ParameterNamesModule();
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<UserBean> create(UserBean userBean){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userBean);
    }

}
```

I use Advanced Rest Client to test, the configuration as below:
[image]

The result look like this:

```
{
   timestamp: "2017-03-12T23:22:20.237+0000"
   status: 400
   error: "Bad Request"
   exception: "org.springframework.validation.BindException"
   errors: [1]
      0:  {
         codes: [4]
            0:  "typeMismatch.userBean.dob"
            1:  "typeMismatch.dob"
            2:  "typeMismatch.java.util.Optional"
            3:  "typeMismatch"
         arguments: [1]
            0:  {
               codes: [2]
                  0:  "userBean.dob"
                  1:  "dob"
               defaultMessage: "dob"
               code: "dob"
            }
         defaultMessage: "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Optional' for property 'dob'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat java.util.Date] for value '1988-10-07'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
         objectName: "userBean"
         field: "dob"
         rejectedValue: "1988-10-07"
         bindingFailure: true
         code: "typeMismatch"
      }
   message: "Validation failed for object='userBean'. Error count: 1"
   path: "/user"
}
```

How can I solve this problem

Comment: do you have this on the class path? (maven deps) https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I have

Comment: ok... does it work for other optionals then? of some other type than `java.util.Date`

Comment: @Eugene I try it with String, Integer without '@JsonFormat' and it work fine

Comment: Please show us the deserializing code or better yet a [mcve]. This works fine for me.

Comment: What are all those other modules? Get rid of all the Spring Boot and Spring MVC stuff, just create an `ObjectMapper` with the same configuration and try to deserialize the JSON. Post the JSON here and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The question is updated. I've found the way to solve this problem by implement Converter of Spring, but if you found the way to solve it by Json annotation, it will be the better.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
```